# How to go through each node in a xml file and return true if the name of the node matches a string and false otherwise using XQuery and XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I want to loop through each node in a xml document and return true if the node is equal to a certain string value and false if not. Output should be similar to:

True
False
False
True
True

True being where the node name matches a string.

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a representative sample of your xml, as well as the string you want to test against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your question as `//*/(. instance of element(foo)` or `for $el in //* return $el instance of element(foo)` (where `foo` would be the name of the element you are looking for).

You couldn't pass it in as a string however, for that you would need `declare $name as xs:string external := 'foo'; //*/(local-name() = $name)`.

Answer (score 0):

If we take your question literally, it's

```
(//node()) ! (if (. = 'a certain string value') then 'True' else 'False'
```

But I suspect that by "node" you really mean element (in which case it's `//*`), and it's possible that by "matches" you mean something other than "=".